# Go to record based on multiple values

Tags: ms-access

I've been scouring around for an answer to this issue, but have been unable to do so thus far, so I thought I might reach out to you all for a little bit of help.

I'm pretty new to MS Access and have been tasked with creating a data entry program that will allow us to enter data into linked sql tables. I have all of the subforms linked up properly and data is getting stored correctly, but I'd like to give end users the ability to go a record based on two values so they're not having to click through the 20k+ records in these tables. I've seen where you can go to a record using a combo box, but all the examples I've seen use only one value to pull up records. My tables are linked by year and then a unique id within each year. What I'd ideally like to do is have two text boxes, one text box the user will enter the records year and the other will contain the recordID, and a button that will call up the corresponding record when pressed. Is that possible? I'd assume that it is. I'm going to continue to keep on doing my own research, but if anyone here could help steer me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How is your form set up?

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this myself, so I kind of wanted to try it.

### Everything we need:

2 Forms, 1 query, and 1 (technically 3) line(s) of VBA.

The "search"/parent form. I created a blank form and called it **Form4**.
I added 2 textboxes, 2 labels, and a button to it.

1. txtSearch1 - Textbox 1
2. txtSearch2 - Textbox 2

I then created a query that filters records by what's in these 2 textboxes. I don't have the same table/schema you did, so bear with me on the names/data types.

My setup:

1. Table: tblEmployee
2. Fields: ID, EmployeeNumber, Names
3. Fields I am filtering: ID, EmployeeNumber

### The Query: (mainly to show how we are filtering)

```
SELECT tbl_Employee.ID,
 tbl_Employee.EmployeeNumber, 
tbl_Employee.FirstName, 
tbl_Employee.LastName
FROM tbl_Employee
WHERE (((tbl_Employee.ID) Like "*" & [Forms]![Form4]![txtSearch2] & "*") 
AND ((tbl_Employee.EmployeeNumber) Like "*" & [Forms]![Form4]![txtSearch1] & "*"));
```

The searches are flexible, as they use wildcards. You can remove these, but I figured the more information the better.

So, we now have a Form with 2 textboxes that we use to narrow down our query results.

Next step, create another form to be inserted into **Form4** to view our search results.

Create a *blank* Form (I named mine **Form5,** hooray). Right click in the top left corner of the Form, and select "Properties".

On the *Format* tab: **Default View**: Datasheet

On the *Data* tab: **Record Source**: Query5 (or your query name)
                 **Recordset Type**: Dynaset

Go back to the form. In design view, in the Access Tool bar at the top, and to the right "Add Existing fields". Add whichever fields you want from your query.

Close **Form5**.

Open **Form4** in Design View. Drag **Form5** onto **Form4**. Save it.

On Form4, right click on the Button we added, or add it if you have not.
Go to Properties, Event -> OnClick -> (click the three little `...`).
Double click on *Code Builder*. Type in `Me.Form5.Requery`. (or `Me.YourFormNameHere.Requery`).

Run Form4 and test your filtering capabilities.